# Serialization and De-serialization of Throwable across JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 using ProtoStuff

Tags: protostuff

We have two system one Running with JDK 1.6 and another with JDK 1.7. To communicate between the two node we are using ProtoStuff Serialization to convert binary & transfer to other node where its again the binary is de-serialized.

JDK 1.7 added new field 'suppressedExceptions', so now if we serialize the Throwable in JDK 1.7 in one node and transfer to another node its not able de-serialize & vice versa.

As two nodes uses different technology its not possible to migrate from JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.7 & JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.6.

Is there any solution to solve this problem, Thanks in advance for the reply.

With Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Protostuff-runtime does not support backward compatibility between two class versions if new field is added to one of base classes. This is caused by `tag` shift - when you add new field to base classe, all `tag` numbers in the childred classes are shifted. So, in general, there is no good solution for your problem.

But if you switch encoding to json, then problem should disappear. With `protostuff-json`, fields are stored using their names (instead of tags), so adding new field in the middle of class hierarchy should not be a problem anymore.